# Working around FFMPEG Mod2 Limitation

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to use ffmpeg to batch process a folder of video files of different sizes, encodes, etc.

We are using the below script. The problem is that we are creating a video from which a subsequent process will extract 3p wide slices. Therefore, an ideal would have mod 3 width. But 264 only expects mod 2. You can see that we are working with mod 6. But in some smaller video files this introduces undesirable artifacts.

The detailed question is: Is there are way to achieve mod 3, perhaps by leveraging anamorphism?

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" \ -vf 'scale=-6:300' \ -c:v h264 -preset "medium" -r 24 \ -map 0:a \ -map 0:v \ -map 0:s \ -map_metadata 0 \ -c:a aac -ac 1 \ -c:s copy \ -y "$partname"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not an absolute limitation. It applies when the output pixel format has subsampled chroma planes, like `yuv420p`, `yuv422p` ..etc.

If your subsequent process can handle yuv444p, then you can simply run

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf 'scale=-3:300,format=yuv444p' \
       -r 24 -c:v libx264 -preset "medium" -map 0:a -map 0:v -map 0:s -map_metadata 0 \
       -c:a aac -ac 1 -c:s copy -y "$partname"
```

But if it can only handle `yuv420p`, then you could pad the scale output with black and have your app discard the last 1 px wide slice.

```
ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf 'scale=-3:300,pad=iw+1:ih' \
       -r 24 -c:v libx264 -preset "medium" -map 0:a -map 0:v -map 0:s -map_metadata 0 \
       -c:a aac -ac 1 -c:s copy -y "$partname"
```